# what i need to do in my code of my website to use CDN servers

Tags: php, lamp, cdn

i am use a **lamp** environment ,

What things I need to pay attention  during the development of the site, 
if the client wants to be ready to use [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network) ?

thanks

Comment: A link to what CDN is might be useful for those who don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is probably to make sure that static assets (images, javascript and CSS, usually) is easily cachable, and movable. We've done this using a special template function that takes a relative URL (something like `/images/graphics/someimage.png`) and turns it into a link to our static server (`http://static.example.com/images/graphics/someimage.png`).

When you have a function that does this, and use it to generate all static asset URLs, it will be trivial later on to move these assets to a different server, or even to different servers based on geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning *Content distribution network* (like Akamai) when you say CDN? If so, then the answer is "it depends."

It depends on which service you use: Each service has different capabilities. Akamai has a full API that you can do all kinds of fun stuff with. Some only do geographical DNS tricks with servers on the east & west coast. Some are in between.

It also depends on what you want to use the service for. Just image hosting? File downloads? Streaming content?

Answer (score 0):

You can also cache dynamic pages, which can bring huge benefits to performance, but remember that you can't cache any pages with personalized data in them.

E.g. say you had a news page updated every hour, you could cache it on the CDN with a TTL (Time-To-Live) of 10 minutes. This would speed up page times and reduce server load.

But if you have any personalised data, for example "Welcome, username" in the banner, you can no longer cache the whole page as it will serve the wrong data to visitors.

One technique to avoid this is to put personalized data in a separate page fragment in a different folder, and load them by AJAX, making sure that this folder is never cached.